# Connect to VMWare Server 1.0.x with Ubuntu 9.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vmware-server, ubuntu-9.10

Does anyone know if there is anything that will install into Ubuntu 9.10 that will let me connect to a remote machine running VMWare server 1.0.x?

I don't care about running VMs on Ubuntu 9.10 itself, I just using something that will allow me to connect another box running VMWare server 1.0.x and view the VM, start and Stop, etc.

'VMWare Server Console' used to (or does) do that, but I don't know what they are calling it this week, or if I can install it into 9.10.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it's still called server console.  Our internal docs reckon that it's only part of the giant furball that is the VMWare server download, though, and it comes as an RPM you need to alienate to make it work on Debian-like systems.  I haven't done anything with it myself, though, so I'm trusting the docs (oh how foolish).

If you're running an i386 system, I have a vmware-server-console deb from 1.0.8 that works on Ubuntu 8.10; I can't imagine it wouldn't work on 9.10.  Ping me on IRC if a copy would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

If thats the original VMware infrastructure client unfortunately it's windows only, the "vmware-cmd" command should allow you to start/stop the VM but you will need to use the VM's services (RDP/SSH etc) to get proper remote control.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work finally in 9.10.

Download the VMware Server 1 client package here: http://register.vmware.com/content/download.html

http://download3.vmware.com/software/vmserver/VMware-server-linux-client-1.0.6-91891.zip

The install (via vmware-install.pl) should complete without any issue.  For me at least, I had an issue with the console in 9.10 where I couldn't use the mouse in a guest outside the edge of the first 640x480 pixels or so.  The problem was described in detail here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1298781

Basically, the fix was to create a launch script that started vmware-server-console with these commands:
export VMWARE_USE_SHIPPED_GTK=force
export GDK_NATIVE_WINDOWS=true
vmware-server-console